# How to compile Java Program with multiple packages

Tags: java, javac

I am lost in reading javac tutorials and still can't compile my program.I have client Server program with two main methods (one for client,one for server).Basically three packages Server with two classes including the Main,Client with the other class with main method and Data package ,Server classes depend on classes from the Data package, how should I compile them so I can start first Server and then Client ?

Comment: Shouldn't compiling them and running them be independent tasks? You should be able to compile them in any order - right?

Comment: Yes ,I can compile them in any order,so can you tell me how to do it ,because I am lost ?

Comment: Please see http://www.dummies.com/how-to/content/how-to-use-the-javac-command.html